# Bro script for reading a list of Ips and domains

Tags: bro

I am trying to read a file with a list of IP addresses and another one with domains, as a proof of concept of the Input Framework defined in https://docs.zeek.org/en/stable/frameworks/input.html

I´ve prepared the following bro scripts:

reading.bro:

```
type Idx: record {
        ip: addr;
};

type Idx: record {
        domain: string;
};


global ips: table[addr] of Idx = table();
global domains: table[string] of Idx = table();

event bro_init() {
    Input::add_table([$source="read_ip_bro", $name="ips",
                      $idx=Idx, $destination=ips, $mode=Input::REREAD]);

    Input::add_table([$source="read_domain_bro", $name="domains",
                      $idx=Idx, $destination=domains, $mode=Input::REREAD]);

    Input::remove("ips");
    Input::remove("domains");
}
```

And the bad_ip.bro script, which check if an IP is in the blacklist, which loads the previous one:

bad_ip.bro

```
@load reading.bro

module HTTP;

event http_reply(c: connection, version: string, code: count, reason: string)
        {
        if ( c$id$orig_h in ips )
                print fmt("A malicious IP is connecting: %s", c$id$orig_h);
        }
```

However, when I run bro, I get the error:

```
error: Input stream ips: Table type does not match index type. Need type 'string':string, got 'addr':addr
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign a `string` type to an `addr` type.  In order to do so, you must use the utility function `to_addr()`.  Of course, it would be wise to verify that that string contains a valid `addr` first.  For example:

```
 if(is_valid_ip(inputString){
   inputAddr = to_addr(inputString)
 } else { print "addr expected, got a string"; }
```

Comment: So, the problem is in **reading.bro** script, before doing `Input::add_table` method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. :)  Zeek is pretty type insistent. :)  It feels natural to use to do an automatic conversion of strings to addresses, but it does not do it.  You will run into the same thing with Counts versus Integers, etc.

Comment: Also, if this is helpful, please accept and upvote.  I'm trying to get enough Bro rep to update the tags... There are so few questions that it's tough to do. :)

Comment: Ok thanks! What feels weird for me is that the example provided by the official documentation is similar to this one and it doesn´t use any kind of conversion

Comment: Yes, the basic problem here is the string/addr incompatibility. But there's more going on ... two things look odd in your code: (1) you define the Idx type twice, (2) you don't assign $val in the Input::add_table call, which leads to the segfault. If you mean to use no $val, the destination data structure must be a set. The segmentation fault here isn't good, though, so I filed a ticket: https://github.com/zeek/zeek/issues/378

Comment: The set stuff isn't called out in the Input Framework docs, unfortunately; you need to have seen [this brief bit in the source](https://github.com/zeek/zeek/blob/master/scripts/base/frameworks/input/main.zeek#L85). We'll hopefully improve this soon.

Comment: Definitely It doesn´t feel right... the problem is, as you said, that the Input Framework doesn´t allow to use another type different from table to store an input. I´ll try your workaround @Christian and I´ll post the solution if I get it. Thanks!

Comment: I´ve solved the problem by adding another field to the register so I can work with tables instead of editing the source. It wasn´t needed to add anything string-related. So Thanks!

Comment: The segfault is now fixed in latest master. Thank you for flagging this @SantiagodeDiego.